# LSTM prediction output for multiple values given a certain time step

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I came across a time series prediction problem where I have a dataset with multiple entries. Each entry represents a value of a certain category in a given time. All the entries are indexed by their timestamp. The entries are separated by a constant time (2 minutes in my case). My goal is to predict all or a subset of the dataset values given a timestamp in the future. However, the majority of the tutorials online are focusing on predicting a single value from the dataset.

My question: Can an LSTM be used to model such problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have the beginning (of some length) of a sequence of values and you need to predict how the sequence continues from there for potentially multiple steps.

You could do that with e.g. a sequence to sequence model. See

www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/seq2seq/

Or

https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html